# Issue with layout of icon in apply button

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

Stack Overflow Careers has a problem with the 'apply' button on job listing pages; the external-link-icon overlaps the texts. Screenshot below shows examples in Chrome and Firefox, respectively.

[image]

Comment: In which browsers, with which version numbers, on which screen size, on which platform?

Comment: The upper screenshot, showing the issue, is Chrome "Version 47.0.2526.73 m" (just updated, issue remains), lower is Firefox "42.0". The window size has no effect, my screen size is 1366 x 768. Windows 8.

Comment: @Hynes this issue/question was resolved but has re-appeared (maybe @DeanWard).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been corrected.

[image]

<strike>Issue was the x-position of the background element wasn't being set. Incorrectly set as a y-position.</strike>

Because of browser support issues, the use of `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` has been replaced with `background-position`. This is still considered status-completed.

Comment: Oh the famous XY syndrome. ;-)

Comment: This issue has re-appeared. Example: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/102074/data-visualization-engineer-r-d-seven-bridges-genomics
Not sure if I should open a new quesion/

Comment: @MikeS When I click on the link you provided, this is what I'm seeing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lBnJA.png

Comment: @Hynes Aha! Firefox doesn't support background-position-[x/y]. It logs "Unknown property 'background-position-y'.  Declaration dropped."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position
Changing it to "background-position: -26px 12px;" fixes the problem

Comment: @MikeS (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻  Ok…

Comment: @MikeS Forgot to mention that a fix (that works in all browsers) went out last night.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick fix (tested in Chrome & Firefox).

```css
a.apply.url{
    background-position: 18px 24px;
    background-origin: border-box;
}
```

[image: screenshot with issue fixed]